# How to enable TaskScheduler in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I'm using `spring-boot` to set up spring defaults.
I'd like to use the `@EnableScheduling` mechanism, and schedule my tasks conditional.

Therefore I have to implement `SchedulingConfigurer` and set `TaskScheduler` explicit.

But when injecting the `TaskScheduler`, I get the following error. But why doesn't spring-boot automatically provide a Scheduler accordingly?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

}

@Service
public class JobService implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    //schedule the task dynamically
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler); //fails
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(task, trigger);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Have you try to setup scheduler via xml config? As for me I have some problems with annotation driven configuration way, but it goes smooth with xml config.

Comment: Because it doesn't. Not everyone needs a scheduler and detecting isn't really possible. So you wil have to add your own.

Comment: Also it is a bit strange that your `SchedulingConfigurer` is a service, would be more logical to be a `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to set a scheduler on the `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`. If one hasn't been configured it defaults to a `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` that wraps a single-threaded scheduled executor:

```java
if (this.taskScheduler == null) {
    this.localExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    this.taskScheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(this.localExecutor);
}
```

If you're happy with this default scheduler you can remove your autowiring of `TaskScheduler` and the call to set it on the `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`. Also, as Marten's suggested in the comments, you should make your `SchedulingConfigurer` a configuration class rather than a service.

These changes leave your code looking something like this:

```
@Configuration
static class TaskConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    //schedule the task dynamically
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(task, trigger);
    }
}
```